# Картинка загрузки страницы перед её открытием, без использования ajax

Tags: ajax, form, загрузка

Есть страница с формой, при нажатии на кнопку submitButton отправляется ajax-запрос и на странице обновляются данные. А в промежутке времени между ajax-запросом и ajax-ответом появляется картинка-вставка, типа ожидание ответа.

Если переделать кнопку не на ajax-запрос, а на открытие новой страницы (т.е. одна страница index.html для ввода данных и нажатия кнопки submitButton, а другая страница result.html для вывода результата), то можно ли вставить эту же картинку-вставку перед тем, как данные обновятся?

Comment: каким образом если вы перейдете на другую страницу вообще?

Comment: В том то и вопрос. Может можно сначала эту заглушку поставить а потом результат обновить?

Comment: Нет. это форма. Костыль JS тоже не получится сделать. с Ajax реально. Если будет другая страница, данные которые были на index.html пропадут. Юзер его даже не увидит.

Comment: Возможно, поможет использование SPA?